# Java Virtual Machine error with Apache Spark after upgrade to 2.2.1

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, jvm, pyspark

I upgraded Apache Spark from 2.1.1 to 2.2.1 (without making any other changes), but now I can't run `spark-submit` or the pyspark shell without errors.

If I try to run the pi calculation example from the command line with `./bin/run-example SparkPi 10` I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: 
class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LogicalRDD overrides final method sameResult.
(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/QueryPlan;)Z
```

Alternatively, if I try to use the shell by running `./bin/pyspark` I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LogicalRDD overrides final method sameResult.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/QueryPlan;)Z

...

ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Exception in thread "Thread-16" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LogicalRDD overrides final method sameResult.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/QueryPlan;)Z

...

ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 177, in getOrCreate
    session = SparkSession(sc)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 211, in __init__
    jsparkSession = self._jvm.SparkSession(self._jsc.sc())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1532, in __getattr__
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: SparkSession does not exist in the JVM
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That is likely an incompatibility between one dependency deriving from another. You have to update your dependencies too.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with dependencies. If I install 2.2.1 into a new directory and use from the new path, spark works without issues. The problem seems to stem from the fact that I installed into the same folder.

Comment: What exactly where the the "install" steps. It indeed looks like you end up with messed up jars from different versions.